# Jest - Testing function that throws an error not working

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have a simple function that throws error if input is lower than 0:

```
export const hoursMinutesSecondsFromSeconds = (inputSeconds) => {
  if (inputSeconds < 0) {
    throw new Error('illegal inputSeconds < 0');
  }
  let rem = Math.abs(inputSeconds);
  let divisor = 3600;
  const result = [];
  while (divisor >= 1) {
    result.push(Math.floor(rem / divisor));
    rem = rem % divisor;
    divisor = divisor / 60;
  }
  return result;
};
```

I am trying to test this function with an input that is lower than 0, like this:

```
import { hoursMinutesSecondsFromSeconds } from './timetools';

describe('hoursMinutesSecondsFromSeconds', () => {
  it('throws error', () => {
    expect(hoursMinutesSecondsFromSeconds(-2)).toThrowError('illegal inputSeconds < 0');
  });
});
```

But, when I run this test, the test fails and I get an error message:

```
Error: illegal inputSeconds < 0
```

Why is this not passing the test, when it throws an error exactly like I am expecting it to throw in my test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible in JavaScript to handle an error that was thrown like `expect(hoursMinutesSecondsFromSeconds(-2))` without wrapping it with `try..catch`.

`toThrowError` is supposed to be used with a function that is internally wrapped with  `try..catch` when it's called. It should be:

```
expect(() => hoursMinutesSecondsFromSeconds(-2)).toThrowError('illegal inputSeconds < 0');
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tothrowerror I expect that you need to wrap your function call in a function.

Like:

```
expect(() => {
    hoursMinutesSecondsFromSeconds(-2);
}).toThrowError('illegal inputSeconds < 0');
```